# iPhone app for random song play

Tags: iphone-app, music

I am looking for a music app that would play songs at random and once a song is played, it would not get played until all the other songs in the music library have been played. The Apple music app is rubbish in that respect: I have ~2,000 songs in my library and more often than not, I get the same one played at least twice in the space of one week, when others haven't been played in months. if the app in question was free, and had a "memory" to remember where it'd stopped when the phone is turned off and back on, all the better. There used to be a great app like this called "Shuffle +", but it's been taken off the app store.

I have looked for such an app high and low and have come up with nothing so far. Can anybody recommend anything that would fit the bill?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the app Stezza. It's a 3rd party app music player for mac. The shuffle hasn't repeated on me but I don't play music much so I can't vouch for it. Nice app though.

I also did a google search for third party mac apps and found this link [of third-party apps.](https://www.cultofmac.com/418199/four-apps-that-offer-a-better-apple-music-experience/) Maybe one on this list fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out OPlayer - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/oplayerhd-lite-media-player-video-file-manager/id385896088?mt=8

I use it instead of the built-in stuff since I'm on a Linux desktop and have no iTunes available.  Transfer files via WiFi on my LAN, has all sorts of repeat modes including "repeat once" and "shuffle", so I think that would randomly play through your list and stop once all items have been played.